# I want to show a specific message when the user fail to login for username and password separately in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am using laravel login api.

I want to show a message for users who fail to login whether it's the username that is not correct or the password the right way.

I looked at AuthenticatesUsers.php there is a method that is responsible for returning a failed login message called sendFailedLoginResponse I edited it so it can do what I want and that's my code.

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{

    $inputemail = $request->input('email');
    $user = User::where('email', $inputemail)->first();

    if($user == '') {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([

            $this->username() => [trans('auth.usernameWrong')],
        ]);
    } else {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'password' => [trans('auth.passwordWrong')],
        ]);
    }
}
```

I know that there is a better way than this becasue I doubly checked the username the first one was laravel check and the second is my query check.

I am new to laravel and I want to know how it can be done the right way.

Comment: Fundamentally: Why not just follow up the stack to `AuthenticateUser()` and push the query through there? To authenticate it shouldn't be passing any username and password without appending both (with or without salting) and encoding as String prior to sending the request...so there is no way for your to get what you want without separate queries (either 2 initially to check user and pass from your Users table separately, or the API query followed by another to check email or pass as you have done)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
{

       // Load user from database
      $user = \App\User::where($this->username(), $request->{$this->username()})->first();

     if(!Hash::check($request->password, $user->password) {
           throw ValidationException::withMessages([

          $this->username() => [trans('auth.passwordWrong')],
       ]);
     } elseif($!user->exists){
         throw ValidationException::withMessages([
           'password' => [trans('auth.usernameWrong')],
      ]);
    }
}
```

Use `Hash::check()` method to check the password

Answer (score 1):

This should help

Go to vendor\laravel\ui\auth-backend\AuthenticatesUsers.php and edit the existing function `sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)`

```
protected function sendFailedLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::where($this->username(), $request->{$this->username()})->first();
        if($user && !Hash::check($request->password, $user->password) ){
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'password' => [trans('auth.password')],
            ]);
        }else{
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            $this->username() => [trans('auth.email')],
        ]);
        }
    }
```

Don't forget to include:

```
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
```

Make sure the above codes are placed inside the vendor\laravel\ui\auth-backend\AuthenticatesUsers.php

Now you can navigate to resources\lang\en\auth.php and include in the code below:

```
'email' => 'The provided email is incorrect.',
'password' => 'The provided password is incorrect.',
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the password with `Hash::check()` method:

```
$user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

if (is_null($user)) {
    // There is no user
} elseif (!Hash::check($request->password, $user->password) {
    // Password is wrong
}
```

Comment: ok but I am still calling a query to check the user email is there any other way to do it without double checking the username and password?

Comment: @loaymansour this is just one query to get both email and password. It's impossible to get the data from DB without a query. If you already executed the same query before in the same request, just pass user instance into a method where you're checking email and password.

Comment: yes I know that but I want to know if there is any way other than that